# mp3 Looping Problems-Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, loops, mp3, flash-cs5

This is so weird, this post wont let me start the sentence with hello hi or howdy maybe cache issue, anyways, hello, i'm very very new to AS3 so my knowledge is limited, hoping you pros can take it easy on the new guy :).
I'm building a flash site with an animation that loops and i've added an mp3 song as background music, it's also set to loop and auto play. the problem is, that the song is longer than the animation, and when the animation goes back to frame 1, the song overlaps the one that's still playing. I'd like for the song to fully finish before it starts playing again.  yeaaah there's probably a heap of code missing, but i got closer to what i want, just need your help to polish it a little.

here is the code so far

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;

//var codes
var AutoPlay:Boolean=true;
var isPlaying:Boolean=false;
var pausePosition:Number=0;
var myMusic:Sound=new Sound();
var soundFile:URLRequest=new URLRequest("Fluke.mp3");
myMusic.load(soundFile);
var channel:SoundChannel;

//if commands
if (AutoPlay==true) {
channel=myMusic.play(pausePosition);
isPlaying=true;
}

//pausebutton functions
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);
function pauseSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
if (isPlaying == false) {
channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
isPlaying =true;
}else{
pausePosition=channel.position;
channel.stop();
isPlaying=false;
}
}

//playbutton functions
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,playMus ic);
function playMusic(event:MouseEvent):void
{ if (isPlaying== false) {
channel=myMusic.play(pausePosition);
isPlaying=true;
}
}
```

**THIS** is the full working code thanks to Josha, with an .addEventListener that i added so that the song would loop after its finished playing.

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


//var codes
var AutoPlay:Boolean=true;
var isPlaying:Boolean;
var pausePosition:Number;
var myMusic:Sound;
var soundFile:URLRequest;
var channel:SoundChannel;

// only create music and register event listeners one time
if (myMusic == null)
{
  soundFile = new URLRequest("Fluke.mp3");
 myMusic = new Sound();
  myMusic.load(soundFile);
 pausePosition = 0;
 if (AutoPlay) 
  {
    channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
isPlaying = true;
  }
  else
  {
isPlaying = false;
}
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
}

channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
function onPlaybackComplete(event:Event) {
pausePosition = 0;
channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
isPlaying = true;
channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
}


//playbutton functions
function pauseSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (isPlaying == false) {
    channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
    isPlaying =true;
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
  }else{
    pausePosition=channel.position;
    channel.stop();
    isPlaying=false;
  }
}

//playbutton functions
function playMusic(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
  if (isPlaying== false) {
    channel=myMusic.play(pausePosition);
    isPlaying=true;
    channel.addEventListener(Event.SOUND_COMPLETE, onPlaybackComplete);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can not place comments yet, so have to use answer.

Are you placing your code in separate AS files; or is this code placed at the first frame of your animation?

If the latter is the case, that indeed you will get overlapping sounds. Since the actionscript code is executed every time the playhead returns to frame 1; creating a new Sound object and starting to play that sound.

A simple solution is to create a key frame at the last frame and add the following action script:

```
gotoAndPlay(2);
```

This will loop your animation from frame 2, skipping over the action script.

Another solution that might work (you would have to test it):

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.media.Sound;
import flash.net.URLRequest;


//var codes
var AutoPlay:Boolean=true;
var isPlaying:Boolean;
var pausePosition:Number;
var myMusic:Sound;
var soundFile:URLRequest;
var channel:SoundChannel;

// only create music and register event listeners one time
if (myMusic == null)
{
  soundFile = new URLRequest("Fluke.mp3");
  myMusic = new Sound();
  myMusic.load(soundFile);
  pausePosition = 0;
  if (AutoPlay) 
  {
    channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
    isPlaying = true;
  }
  else
  {
    isPlaying = false;
  }
  pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseSound);
  play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playMusic);
}

//playbutton functions
function pauseSound(e:MouseEvent):void
{
  if (isPlaying == false) {
    channel = myMusic.play(pausePosition);
    isPlaying =true;
  }else{
    pausePosition=channel.position;
    channel.stop();
    isPlaying=false;
  }
}

//playbutton functions
function playMusic(event:MouseEvent):void
{ 
  if (isPlaying== false) {
    channel=myMusic.play(pausePosition);
    isPlaying=true;
  }
}
```

Comment: dude, thank you so much, i was going nuts trying to figure this out. I had to add an event listener so that it would loop.For all rookies like me trying to do the same, the full working code, thanks to Josha, is edited on my first post.

Comment: your welcome :) Happy coding; if you are going to add more actionscript you might wanna check out how to link a MovieClip to an external actionscript file.